# LINQ Query and DateTimes

Tags: c#-3.0, linq-to-objects

I'm trying to get the `Sum()` from an `Entityset<MyObject>` with the next query.

```
(from MyObject p in SelectedObject.MyObjectEntitySet
where p.AColumn.HasValue && 
p.ADate >= dateTimeValue &&
p.ADate <= dateTimeValue2
select p.AColumn.Value).Sum();
```

with no luck retrieving correct sum.

Any Ideas?

[EDIT] OK WORKED!

Comment: We can't possible tell what's wrong from that. Essentially you've said "this query isn't giving the result I expected" without saying what result it *is* giving or why you expected anything different.

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot the query by breaking it up into its constituent parts, and examining the output of each part:

```
var entitySet = SelectedObject.MyObjectEntitySet;
var entitySetWithValues = entitySet.Where(p => p.AColumn.HasValue);
var entitySetGreater = entitySetWithValues.Where(p => p.ADate >= DateTimeValue);
```

...and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the list of overloads, the Sum method is over numeric values (decimal, float, int, double, long, etc). The selector has to be a function that takes a DateTime and returns a numeric value.

[edit]
Sorry, I didn't realize that AColumn was numeric.